# Why would certain Sitecore content not be indexed by Solr?

Tags: sitecore, solr4, sitecore7.5

I have a site built using Sitecore 7.5 and Solr 4.7. I am noticing a very strange phenomenon where certain content items are not getting indexed.  Here is what is happening.

I have a data template called "Content Page".  Most of the content items that are using this data template live in /sitecore/content/Home/Corporate.  Things like this:

```
/sitecore/content/Home/Corporate/About-Us
/sitecore/content/Home/Corporate/Careers
/sitecore/content/Home/Corporate/Terms-Of-Use
```

There are a few test items that I created that live in /sitecore/content like this:

```
/sitecore/content/Test-1
/sitecore/content/Test-2
```

All of these pages are built using the "Content Page" data template.  After I rebuild the index and then go to the Solr UI and do a query I can't find any of the items that live beneath the Home node.  When I do a query for _templatename:"Content Page" - I only get Test-1 and Test-2 in the results.  Does anyone know why this would be happening?  It's really odd.  I've never seen something where Solr just doesn't index certain items at all.  And it seems to be based on where they are in the content tree.

Comment: Are you able to share your index configuration?

Comment: Is your site multi-language?

Comment: What's the `locations\root` setting of your index configuration? Is this happening in both master and web? And also as @MartinDavies and @PatrickPerrone above.

Comment: Anything in logs? can you share your Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.config files?

Comment: I actually think I figured this one out.  When I originally configured Solr with my Sitecore instance I used the StructureMap IOC container.  I think for some reason it wasn't working well.  I switched to using the CastleWindsor IOC container and all of these problems went away!

Answer (score 3):

[According to Pavel Veller on the Sitecore forums](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/p/237/1767#1767), answering a question similar to yours:

> First, there are different fallback strategies. Field-level is most
>   likely done via the StandardValuesProvider and yes, you need to have a
>   version in the language for the fallback to kick in. We built a
>   Language Tool wizard in SCORE that can create empty language versions
>   to help in exactly this scenario. You can also do item-level fallback
>   with ItemProvider which will make it appear as if an item had a
>   version in the language even if it doesn't. The good thing about both
>   is that you fallback on the Sitecore API level. Services like search
>   crawlers and publishing all work via those APIs (until you wrote your
>   own, of course) and as a result they all "see" the fallback.
>   Publishing will actually "materialize" the fallback value and the
>   crawler on CD will work with the items and field values as if those
>   were real.